# FabricMC Change Text from TextRender.draw

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am fairly new to modding in Minecraft however I know a decent amount. What I need help with is rendering text on the screen, I would like to be able to render some text and update what is displayed as the text, here is what I have.

```
client.textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("Text"), 5, 10, 1);
```

If you know how I would go about changing the text after rendering, or have a different way of rendering text to make this, please say. Thank you!

I have tried rendering the text as a variable as an int but that didn't allow me to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the text object in a field of whatever class you're drawing the text in - and then pass the field instead of a text object:

```java
client.textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, this.textToDraw, 5, 10, 1);
```

Take this abstracted example:

```java
public class Example {
  private Text textToDraw = Text.empty();

  public void render(MinecraftClient client) {
     // ...
    client.textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, textToDraw, 5, 10, 1);

  }
}

// ...
// I want to now render "Hello World!"
textToDraw = Text.literal("Hello World!");
```